# Second Conjugate space and boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

> $Theorem$..Let $X$ be a Banach normed space and $C \subseteq X^*$.IF $\forall x \in X$ we have $\sup\limits_{f \in X*}|f(x)|< \infty$ then $\sup\limits_{f \in X^*}||f|| < \infty$.

This theorem is an application of Uniform bound principle in a collection of bounded linear functionals.

> $Exercise$..Let $X$ be a normed space and $M \subseteq X^*$ and $Y \subseteq X$.
>   If $M$ is a set of second category in $X$( in other words it cannot be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense subsets)and $\sup\limits_{x \in Y}|f(x)| < \infty,\forall f \in M$,then prove that $\sup\limits_{x \in Y}||x||< \infty$

Now if the exercise instead of $M$ had the whole conjugate space which is Banach then I could apply the above theorem in $X^*$ and $X^{**}$ using the property of  isometry of the normal embbeding $J:X \longrightarrow X^{**}$ where $J(x)=v_x$ and $v_x:X^* \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$(or $\mathbb{C}$) where $v_x(f)=f(x)$.

Now we have  the condition that $M$ is a set of second category.

I tried to solve this exercise  modifying the proofs of the above theorem and  of uniform bound principle.

Here is my attempt:Let $A=\{u_x:M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}|x \in Y\}$. We know from hypothesis that $\sup\{|v_x(f)|:v_x \in A\}=\sup\limits_{x \in Y}{|f(x)|}< \infty$

Now define $B_n=\{f \in M:|v_x(f)| \leqslant n,\forall  x \in Y\}$

Let $f_0 \in M$ then $\sup\limits_{x \in Y}|f_0(x)| \leqslant C$ for some $C>0$ ,thus $|v_x(f_0)|=|f_0(x)| \leqslant C \leqslant[C]+1,\forall x \in Y$ so $f \in B_{[C]+1} \subseteq \bigcup_nB_n$ proving that $M=\bigcup_nB_n$ .

Because of the fact that $M$ is of  second category ,$\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $cl(B_{n_0}) \neq \emptyset$ thus $\exists g \in M$ and $R >0$ such that $O=D(g,R) \subseteq B_{n_0}$

$\forall f \in D_0(g,0)$ we have that $|v_x(f)| \leqslant |v_x(g)|+|v_x(f+g)| \leqslant 2N$

Thus $\forall f \in D_0,\forall x \in Y$ we have that $|u_x(f)| \leqslant 2N(=n_0)$

Now for all  $f \neq 0^*$ and forall $t>1$ we have that $|v_x(\frac{Rf}{||f||t})|\leqslant 2N \Longrightarrow |v_x(f)| \leqslant \frac{2Nt||f||}{R} ,\forall x \in Y$

Taking $t \longrightarrow 1$ we have that $||v_x|| \leqslant 2N/R,\forall x \in Y,\forall  f \in X^*$,thus $\sup\limits_{x \in Y}||x||=\sup\limits_{v_x \in A}||v_x||< \infty$

because $v_x$ is an isometry.

Can someone help me see if this proof is correct or correct it in case it is wrong?

Thank you in advance!